# Representing "if and only if" concisely

Tags: clingo

Suppose you happen to know that `$P` is true if and only if `$Q` is true.  You can write a pair of integrity constraints to enforce this:

```
:- $P, not $Q.
:- $Q, not $P.
```

However, sometimes `$P` and `$Q` are fairly long expressions; e.g., `:- truth(martin, 2), house_assign(turner, H1), animal_assign(P2, whales), house_assign(P2, H2), not opposite(H1, H2).` and it would be preferable to only have to write them once. Is there a way to concisely specify this in clingo?

(Related: Q4 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28319815/23845 ; the suggestion there is explicitly represent the truthiness of P/Q in the predicate, so you can do a comparison on it. Is this really the only way?)

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```
:- {$P; $Q}==1.
```

However it does not seem to work for conjuctions within `$P` and `$Q`.

So my fix would look something like this ((`a(N)` and `b(N)`) iff `c(N)`):

```
{a(1);a(2);b(1);b(2);c(1);c(2)}.    
num(1;2)

x(N):-a(N),b(N).
:- {x(N);c(N)}==1, num(N).
```